# How do I integrate a timed loop in pyqt

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I'm working on a pyqt-gui, which should have the possibility to refresh data loading every chosen time (for example every 2 minutes). During this loop, the gui should be able to respond to events etc.

The code looks like this:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.uic import *
class TeleModul (QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        loadUi ("telemodul.ui",self)
        .....
    def on_ButtonSuchen_clicked (self):
        QTimer.singleShot(60000, self.RefreshData())
    def RefreshData(self):
        ...do something ...
```

Clicking on ButtonSuchen evokes an error:

> TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
>   QTimer.singleShot(int, QObject, SLOT()): argument 2 has unexpected
>   type 'NoneType'   QTimer.singleShot(int, callable): argument 2 has
>   unexpected type 'NoneType'

What's the fault or what's the best way to integrate this loop?

Comment: Everything you wanted to know about QTimer but feared to ask: http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/weblog/posts/BB974.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the callable, not the result of calling it:

```
QTimer.singleShot(60000, self.RefreshData)
```

Comment: Is there a way to know if there is an overrun (i.e. if self.RefreshData took longer than 60000)?